# Why does Active Record use module_eval internally for certain features?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I've noticed a few places in the Rails source code where `module_eval` is used. One place is in [ActiveRecord::Enum](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/98ebec1f61a49b0b9f55db8c633726cfc0170dc0/activerecord/lib/active_record/enum.rb#L91-L131) and another is in [ActiveRecord::Store](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/0ac16326d20e1ce8d0b3af363012b17a3c8b6086/activerecord/lib/active_record/store.rb#L83-L93). I'm familiar with `class_eval` and `instance_eval` and have used them for extending the functionality of existing classes or objects, but in the case of `module_eval`, it seems like it's serving a different purpose.

In both cases they are using a similar pattern to define the module:

```
def _store_accessors_module
  @_store_accessors_module ||= begin
    mod = Module.new
    include mod
    mod
  end
end
```

If the module is being included in the class it's defined in, what benefit is there to defining related methods in a nested module like this? Is it better isolation of code? The reason I'm asking is because I have a gem that adds functionality to Active Record, and am wondering if this approach is more of a "best practices" way of doing the same thing. [Here's the relevant source code of my gem](https://github.com/beerlington/classy_enum/blob/master/lib/classy_enum/active_record.rb#L30-L103) for reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the methods are being defined in a nested module is so that users may override the methods and still have access to `super` to get at the original functionality. Recall that when you include modules in Ruby they are inserted into the ancestors list for the current class and `super` works by simply iterating through the ancestors array, looking for the first object that responds to the current method. To this end, the name of the module is not important as it is simply an inheritance-chain-like delivery mechanism. So that's why they define just an anonymous new module and include it on the fly.

If you look at the blame view for the 2 examples you listed, you can see the reasoning behind the changes. The [commit message in the ActiveRecord::Store example](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/9dfef5a46bb6a0c74a48aa70fa350c0f09f92c0d#diff-35b4b9d1f71c473aeaf24e1826bf3387R72) makes the case pretty well. As you can see, they're adding the ability to override the accessor definition `color` and tack on to the results of the original method via `super || 'red'`. Whereas, in the original implementation, one would have to both override the `color` accessor method and then do the same work as the original accessor method, i.e. call `read_store_attribute(:settings, :color) || 'red'`. So it's all about not being forced to reproduce the internals or using alias method chains to augment the functionality of the dynamically defined methods.

I'm not sure whether this is a useful feature in your gem, but I'm guessing maybe not as your accessors seem to be returning well-defined object enum-related objects. But, of course, that's up to you and the gem's users :).

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation!